# Power BI Paginated Report or SSRS render faster?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a rdl report build with Power BI report builder and it's embedding on web with Power BI embedded SKU A2. It render very slow.

I'm wondering if I change this report to SSRS, will it be faster?

Comment: PowerBI paginated reports are based on SSRS, normally performance on both products on the same server will be the same

Comment: Give it a try and let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a SSRS Report RDL file is quite small as it does not contain all the data from the data sources, so SSRS report render fast compared to Power BI paginated reports. It’s difficult to choose between SSRS and Power BI report builder it depends on what solution you are aiming for from the business intelligence tool. You can continue using Power BI by optimizing report and make it render fast.

Find the references here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/admin/service-premium-capacity-optimize
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-performance-best-practices